# Is an Awakened land an OK target for Ruins of Oran-Rief?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

I have an Awaken deck and I want to use [Ruins of Oran-Rief](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Ruins%20of%20Oran-Rief). If I awaken a land that I placed on the battlefield earlier on the same turn, does it count as a legal target?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is "summoning sickness" and how does it affect my creatures?](http://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/25234/what-is-summoning-sickness-and-how-does-it-affect-my-creatures)

Comment: It's not completely clear what you are asking, but I believe the linked question will have what you need.

Comment: I've given this some editing. The original first sentence was a red herring for understanding the question (there's no "enters the battlefield" trigger that's relevant here), and I've just put the intent up front and rephrased.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you can use Ruins of Oran-Rief on that Awakened land - as long as, like you're describing, you played that land in the same turn.

The ability in question is this one, I presume:

> {T}: Put a +1/+1 counter on target colorless creature that entered the battlefield this turn.

After your land's awakened, it's a colorless creature (as well as a land). That colorless creature *did* also enter the battlefield this turn. So, yes, at this point it meets all the prerequisites for targeting with this ability: it's a colorless creature that entered the battlefield this turn.

This is confirmed in a ruling on Ruins of Oran-Rief's gatherer page:

> 1/22/2016 - The target of the last ability didn’t necessarily have to be a colorless creature as it entered the battlefield, provided it entered the battlefield during that turn. However, it does have to be a colorless creature to be a legal target of the ability.

Comment: You can quote the ruling on Oran for this too.

Comment: Would the land have to have been played the same turn as it got awakened though? I.e.: does a land "re-enter" the battlefield as a creature when you awaken it? (I thought it didn't, as transforms and other kind of things also don't count as "entering the battlefield")

Comment: @Laurens The question is about Awakening a land that did enter the battlefield in the same turn - but I'll edit to make that clear. Good thing to cover. :)