# What happens when Illusory Gains is detached during combat?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

Player 1 has [Arcades Sabboth](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bArcades%20Sabboth%5d) onto the battlefield.
Player 2 has [Garna,The Bloodflame](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bGarna%2cThe%20Bloodflame%5d) onto the battlefield.
In Player 2's main phase, he cast [Illusory Gains](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bIllusory%20Gains%5d) on Arcades Sabboth, to gain control of the Elder Dragon; and, in the subsequent combat phase, declares Arcades Sabboth as an attacker, tapping him.
In the declaring blockers sub-phase, the defending player (player 1) summons Plaxmanta - spending green mana - thanks to his Flash Ability.

Consequently, this question arises, which I am now going to explain in detail.

Since Illusory Gains' triggered ability is now on the stack, and the creature to which Illusory Gains is to be assigned is the just summoned Plaxmanta, I was wondering which of the two is the right one:

**1) Arcades Sabboth continues to be tapped and attacking**, as declared by player 2 during the sub-phase, **and therefore remains on his side**, until the end of the combat phase; or,

**2) Arcades Sabboth, since Illusory Gains has been "detached", is no longer under the control of player 2**, **and returns under the control of player 1**, but tapped and removed from the fight.

In all this situation, Plaxmanta is in any case now enchanted by Illusory Gains, and therefore it is under the control of player 2.
But it is good to clarify whether the combat phase has significantly changed since his entering onto the battlefield, in a case like the one described.    And for this purpose my question is addressed.

**The particular dynamics of Illusory Gains, namely the fact that this card can "detach" from one creature to enchant another in various situations, makes this question a little different from various others, in my opinion**.
  Also the fact that Illusory Gains can be attached to creatures that have hexproof or shroud makes this card - and the situations related to it - really particular, and therefore it may need more explanations and clarifications from expert players.

Comment: Although not the focus of the question, it's worth mentioning that Arcades Sabboth can't attack the turn that it was enchanted by Illusory Gains without some source of haste. Summoning Sickness applies to creatures that changed controllers, so even though Arcades Sabboth has been on the field for several turns, it hasn't been under the opponent's control during their upkeep. Since the specific creature being stolen doesn't matter for your question, I suggest changing Arcades Sabboth to a creature with haste to avoid this issue.

Comment: The fact that the creature is Arcades Sabboth does nothing at all to this question - there's no reason for the massive image of that creature in here. If there was going to be an image of a card it should have been Illusory Gains.

Comment: @Aetherfox and most likely (though not impossible) the owner of Illusory Gains won't be playing Bant and would have had to sacrifice it before it was able to attack.

Comment: You're right Andrew...but, ehm...I was sure that someone would have pointed out to me about this ... but...that I have to do it if ... er, Arcades Sabboth is ... you see ... he is a BEAST !!! I wanted it to be clear. But  I awaited your warning too. Then I would have deleted it by myself!

Comment: No....I only read this now ... I can't believe it: are creatures that change controllers affected by summoning sickness also when they are not just summoned creatures??? But this is a big nonsense, it can't be true! And if so, since when did they change this rule ?? Please Aetherfox, or anyone else, answer here my small but fundamental sub-question! Thank you.

Comment: @ManoFromBerlin: Yes, changing control of creatures 'reactivates' summoning sickness. Note that summoning sickness checks if the creature has been under their current controller's continuous control since their controller's last upkeep. This question (example 4) addresses it: https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/25234/what-is-summoning-sickness-and-how-does-it-affect-my-creatures
I have no idea when/if the rule changed, but it's why you see a lot of temporary steal cards, like Traitorous Instinct, give haste for the turn as well.

Comment: Well, as usual, in some way, yes,the questions are very similar. But:1) the question of summoning sickness has now also emerged, applicable also to stolen creatures,makes me think that this question could be useful just the same (even if, obviously, especially for me!).2)Furthermore, the dynamics of Illusory Gains could be different from that shown in the linked question, since the mechanism of "detach" sometimes works in a particular way. For example, Illusory Gains can be assigned to a creature with hexproof or shroud , and it is also for this "pitfall" that I asked the question .

Comment: So overall, I would say that albeit with many similarities, the two questions are still a little different,as I expressed in the request box that was sent to me.

Comment: Does the post about summoning sickness that Aetherfox linked address your question about summoning sickness?

Comment: @ManoFromBerlin what we call summoning sickness is in the rules "A creature’s activated ability with the tap symbol or the untap symbol in its activation cost can’t be activated unless the creature has been under its controller’s control continuously since their most recent turn began. A creature can’t attack unless it has been under its controller’s control continuously since their most recent turn began."

Comment: Ok ... it's unbelievable, but it's true; if the rule prescribes what Andrew wrote in the comment, then it is so. I remember that in the past the rule was different. Now, the whole thing is actually governed by rule 302.6, which says exactly what Andrew indicated. Thank you for the clarifications ... as you can see, even if this question could be considered a duplicate of a question already present in SE, it is still a question that has been useful: for me, and also for other users. Ok...now, I'm going to edit my question, giving Arcades Sabboth a way to grant haste...

Comment: However, as far as the removal of the massive image of Arcades Sabboth is concerned ... anyone can notice that it was a whole other thing before:much, much better. But ... be afraid! Arcades Sabboth will punish you for what you have done !! Don't even imagine what awaits you for having removed its huge image !!!

Comment: However,the rule of summoning sickness that must also be applied to stolen creatures is a contradiction in terms ... why must stolen creatures have a  weakness from evocation,if they were summoned 100 years ago?Jet Lag for what?For a plane taken 10 years ago?Ok,as usual, it is the actual "rule"...but I think it is unsense...Another one of these new honeyed in syrup rules.However this is my opinion, even it does not matter to anyone, obviously...But please, think about it... Probably,I do too much of that "Poetry Magic" of mine.But it is also unreceivable, looking at all these bad changements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Number 2 is correct (Arcades is no longer attacking and returns to player 2).

> 506.4. **A permanent is removed from combat** if it leaves the battlefield, **if its controller changes**, if it phases out, if an effect
>   specifically removes it from combat, if it’s a planeswalker that’s
>   being attacked and stops being a planeswalker, or if it’s an attacking
>   or blocking creature that regenerates (see rule 701.14) or stops being
>   a creature. **A creature that’s removed from combat stops being an**
>   **attacking, blocking, blocked, and/or unblocked creature.** A
>   planeswalker that’s removed from combat stops being attacked.

(emphasis mine)