# Can tapping for another card, also activate that card ability?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

If I have in play a [Selesnya Evangel](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Selesnya%20Evangel) and tap [Tolsimir Wolfblood](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Tolsimir%20Wolfblood) to create a Saproling, can I create the 2/2 green/white Voja too? Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not in the way you describe; both abilities require tapping the Wolfblood *as part of their cost*; you can't pay one cost to pay for both abilities.

Think of it this way: if a fries and a soda each cost $1 (and you only have $1), you can get one or the other, but not both.

Abilities in Magic the Gathering are written as {cost}:{effect}.

Selesnya Evangel's ability says:

> 1, T, Tap an untapped creature you control: Create a 1/1 green Saproling creature token.

Paying for this ability requires 1 mana, tapping the Evangel, *and tapping another untapped creature you control*.

Tolsimir Wolfblood's ability says:

> T: Put a legendary 2/2 green and white Wolf creature token named Voja into play.

Paying for this ability only requires tapping Tolsimir.

You *could*, however, change the order and do the following:

1. Activate Tolsimir's ability to create the wolf token
2. Then activate Selesnya Evangel, *tapping the newly created wolf token*, to creature a Saproling.

Note that there are abilities that work more like your original idea, but they're worded much differently. For example, check out [Emmara, Soul of the Accord](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Emmara%2C%20Soul%20of%20the%20Accord):

> Whenever Emmara, Soul of the Accord becomes tapped, create a 1/1 white Soldier creature token with lifelink.

Emmara has a *triggered ability* that creates a token whenever it becomes tapped, for any reason (when she attacks, or tapping her for the Evangel's ability, or if it got tapped down by an opponent's [Benalish Trapper](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Benalish%20Trapper)).

Comment: I see, so is it possible to tap permanents during the turn they are played if its not to attack or it works just because the permanent is a token created from an ability instead that from the deck? Sorry for the confusion, it's been quite a while and I'm trying to re-learn.

Comment: @IStoleTheMuffin you will want to read https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/25234/what-is-summoning-sickness-and-how-does-it-affect-my-creatures

Comment: No problem, and you've hit on a key point: you can't tap a creature *for its own ability* on the turn it comes into play (unless it has haste), but the Evangel's "Tap an untapped creature you control" cost doesn't have that restriction, so you can tap the newly-created wolf token to help pay for this ability.

Comment: Not exactly true. It's the tap symbol. Abilities like [mtg:Heritage Druid] can tap themselves the turn they come in.